# EF 6 access key table in m:n relation

Tags: entity-framework

I have a EF 6 code first model with a n:m relation.
The table between Courses and Interests has the keys
This2Courses and This2Interests.

I use

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Course>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Interests)
            .WithMany(e => e.Courses)
            .Map(m => {
                m.ToTable("Interests2Courses");
                m.MapLeftKey("This2Course");
                m.MapRightKey("This2Interest");
            });


        modelBuilder.Entity<Interest>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Courses)
            .WithMany(e => e.Interests)
            .Map(m => {
                m.ToTable("Interests2Courses");
                m.MapLeftKey("This2Interest");
                m.MapRightKey("This2Course");
            });
```

In the course class I have

```
        public virtual ICollection<Interests2Courses> Interests2Courses { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Interest> Interests { get; set; }
```

which works fine for the Interests collection.
But when I try to access (load) the linking table like this:

```
Course cO = dbC.Courses.Include(a => a.Interests2Courses).FirstOrDefault(a => a.ShortName == "K1");
```

I get an exception: Invalid object name dbo.Interests2Courses1

So I'm only able to access either "simple n:m" or the linking table.
Is there a way to access both?

Comment: One of the mappings is redundant and you should remove `Interests2Courses`. See [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) how HasMany/WithMany works in EF6.

Comment: You are right - but unfortunately this doesn't answer my question. I came to this by playing around with several variants to solve my problem.

Comment: It does answer your question: you can't do both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So every `Course` will have zero or more `Interests`, while every `Interest` will have zero or more `Courses`. You are right, in a relational database this is implemented using a junction table. However, your entity framework is an abstraction of your database, you don't need to define this junction table:

```
class Course
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    ...

    // every Course has zero or more Interests (many-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<Interest> Interests {get; set;}
}
class Interest
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    ...

    // every Interest has zero or more Courses(many-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses{get; set;}
}
```

For completeness the dbContext

```
class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Course> Courses {get; set;}
    public DbSet<Interest> Interests {get; set;}
}
```

This is all that entity framework needs to know to identify your tables, the columns in the tables and the many-to-many relationship. Although you didn't mention the junction table, entity framework will create one for for you.

There is no need for attributes, nor fluent API. Only if you are not satisfied with the default identifiers that Entity Framework invents for you you'll need fluent API.

**But how can I (group-)join Courses and Interests if I can't access the junction table?**

Answer: don't do a (group-)join, use the virtual ICollections!

> Give me all (or some) Courses with all (or some) of its Interests

```
var result = dbContext.Courses
    .Where(course => ...)       // only if you don't want all Courses
    .Select(course => new
    {
        // only select the properties you actually plan to to use
        Id = course.Id,
        Name = course.Name,
        ...

        Interests = course.Interests
            .Where(interest => ...)  // only if you don't want all its Interests
            .Select(interest => new
            {
                 Id = interest.Id,
                 ...
            })
            .ToList(),
    });
```

Entity framework knows your many-to-many and will do the proper group-join for you. Or course you can do this the other way round: "give me all interests with their courses"

### Addition after comment

If your junction table is not a pure junction table, because it has some properties you need to add it to your DbContext. In that case you'll have to add a class that represents this JunctionItem.

TODO: invent a name that properly describes what this JunctionItem represents

Note that your many-to-many relation between Courses and Interests change to a one-to-many between Courses and Junction. Relation between Junction and Interests also changes to one-to-many.

```
class Course
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    ...

    // every Course has zero or more JunctionItems (one-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<JunctionItem> JunctionItems {get; set;}
}
class Interest
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    ...

    // every Interest has zero or more JunctionItems(one-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<JunctionItem> JunctionItems{get; set;}
}
```

The new JunctionItem class:

```
class JunctionItem
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    ... // other JunctionItem properties

    // every JunctionItem belongs to exactly one Course (using foreign key)
    public int CourseId {get; set;}
    public virtual Course Course {get; set;}

    // every JunctionItem belongs to exactly one Interest (using foreign key)
    public int InterestId {get; set;}
    public virtual Interest Interest {get; set;}
}
```

And the DbContext:

```
class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Course> Courses {get; set;}
    public DbSet<Interest> Interests {get; set;}

    public DbSet<JunctionItem> JunctionItems {get; set;}
}
```

Because you defined the relations as virtual properties, entity framework already detected your one-to-many relationships, so you don't have to inform the modelbuilder about these relations. However, if you want:

```
var junctionEntity = modelBuilder.Entity<JunctionItem>();

// every junctionEntity has one-to-many with Course:
junctionEntity.HasRequired(junction => junction.Course)
   .WithMany(course => course.JunctionEntities)
   .HasForeignKey(junction => junction.CourseId);
```

Something similar for the interests:

```
junctionEntity.HasRequired(junction => junction.Interest)
    .WithMany(interest => interest.JunctionEntities)
    .HasForeignKey(junction => junction.InterestId);
```

Note: an optimization would be to combine JunctionTable.CourseId and JunctionTable.InterestId into one composite primary key:

```
junctionEntity.HasKey(junction => new {junction.CourseId, junction.InterestId});
```

This prohibits that two separate JunctionItems point to the same (Course, Interest) combination:

```
Course courseA = ...
Interest interestB = ...

// not possible:
JunctionInterest j1 = new JunctionInterest {Course = courseA, Interest = interestB};
JunctionInterest j2 = new JunctionInterest {Course = courseA, Interest = interestB};
```

If you want this, you'll need a separate primary key in your JunctionItem.

Your queries will be similar as your pure many-to-many, but now they are one-to-many. Do not use join, use the ICollection:

```
var result = dbContext.Courses
    .Select(course => new
    {
        Id = course.Id
        Name = course.Name,
        ...

       JunctionItems = course.JunctionItems.Select(junctionItem => new
       {
            ... // junction item properties

            Interests = junctionItem.Interest.Select(interest => new
            {
                 ... // interest properties
            })
            .ToList(),
       })
       .ToList(),
    });
    });
```

Comment: I use annotations because the db exist. My question was about accessing the linking table because this has (besides the keys) additional fields.

Comment: Thank you Harald, that was exactly what I'm looking for -- I din't tell in the question - but my junction table has an extra field "IsFavorite", so that I can show that specific courses are favorites for this interest.